# Prove that these statements about the integer x: If 3x + 7 is even, then x + 3 is even

Tags: homework

Then there exists some integer k where x=2k
So 3x+7=3(2k)+7  6k+7
This is as far as Ive got.

Comment: This site is for Mathematica the software, not mathematics. I think you wanted to ask this on [math.SE].

Comment: Also your first statement isn't quite right. You wanted that there exists some integer k such that (3x + 7)/2=k.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol = Solve[{Mod[3 x + 7, 2] == 0}, x, Integers][[1]]

(* {x -> ConditionalExpression[1 + 2 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]} *)

Mod[x + 3, 2] == 0 /. sol // Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &

(* True *)
```